# Annoying svn issue where svn claims folder is under version control but no .svn exists

Tags: xcode, svn, version-control, smartsvn

I have a folder that both XCode and SmartSVN both claim is "already under version control." However, when I run `svn status` in that folder, it says it is not a working copy. Furthermore, I cannot add or subtract the folder from the working copy in SVN, for if I add it (with or without recursion) it claims it is already under version control, and yet there is no context option for me to remove it from said version control.

Furthermore, when I check to see if there is a `.svn` folder in that directory, there is not.

I have tried `svn cleanup` in the working directory root as well as the directory in question. When performed at the root it completes with no messages. When performed in the directory, it informs me that it is not a working copy.

It is causing an annoying `Obstructing -` warning in XCode that is bugging me.

If anyone knows what I am talking about or has experienced the same thing please help me out!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It happens when the parent folder gets out of sync with some of its children. A possible workaround is renaming the parent folder offline (using the file system, not via svn), get a fresh copy from the repository and then bring back your modifications from the renamed folder (excluding the`.svn` ones).

When finished delete the renamed folder. Otherwise you might end up with broken folders:

> If you renaming a project, Xcode does not remove the .svn directory in
>   the .xcodeproj. As a result, svn gets confused, thinking the renamed
>   project directory is under version control
>   [[source]](http://confluence.gordonturner.ca/display/NOTES/Xcode+and+svn+notes)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure XCode and SmartSVN are expecting the right version of you SVN installation. After last upgrade of SVN, I noticed that things have changed in how SVN handles things. Everything is now stored in the root checkout folder, and you don't have `.svn` folder in ech sub folder anymore.